# make TLD array to under gtld

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a big tLD array of 2200 items like:

```
$TestArray = array(".aero", ".airport.aero", ".cargo.aero", ".charter.aero", ".aetna");
```

i am want to convert them as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tld] => .aero
            [gTLD] => Array ( [0] => .airport.aero [1] => .cargo.aero [2] => .charter.aero )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tld] => .aetna
            [gTLD] => 
        )

)
```

You can see my code below:

```
$TldList = array();

$TestArray = array(".aero", ".airport.aero", ".cargo.aero", ".charter.aero", ".aetna");


foreach ($TestArray as $tld)
{

    $LocalTld = array();
    $TldBreakPoints = explode(".",$tld);

    $gTLD = array();

    $found = false;

    if((count($TldBreakPoints)) > 2)
    {

        foreach ($TestArray as $tld2)
        {

            $TldBreakPoints2 = explode(".",$tld2);

            if((count($TldBreakPoints2)) > 2)
            {
                if($tld == '.'.$TldBreakPoints2[2])
                {
                     echo 'match gtld';
                    $found = true;

                    $gTLD[] = $tld2;

                }else{

                    //Nothing
                }

            }else{
                // Nothing
            }



        }

    }else{

    }
    

    $LocalTld['tld'] = $tld;

    if($found)
    {

        $LocalTld['gTLD'] = $gTLD;

    }else{

        $LocalTld['gTLD'] = '';

    }
    $TldList[] = $LocalTld;

}

echo '<pre>';

print_r($TldList);
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Is it always true that: "The gTLDs appear in the array after the TLD they will be assigned to."?  This is not explicitly stated in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [ '.aero', '.airport.aero', '.cargo.aero', '.charter.aero', '.aetna' ];

$result = array_values(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function ($carry, $item) {
          if (substr_count($item, '.') === 1) {
            $carry[$item] = [ 'tld' => $item, 'gTLD' => [] ];
          } else {
            $parts = preg_split('/^([.].+)([.].+)/', $item, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE + PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            $last = end($parts);
            $carry[$last]['gTLD'][] = $item;
          }
          return $carry;
        },
        []
    )
);

print_r($result);
```

Assumptions:

- The TLDs contain only one dot.
- The gTLDs appear in the array after the TLD they will be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

If `gTLD`s always appear after the `tld` has been encountered, then the task can be reduced significantly.  This task merely needs each string to be parsed so that the determination about `gTLD` can be made, then push data into the desired group with the desired associative elements.

`preg_match()`, below, is not only checking if the string value contains a `gTLD` value, but also isolates the `tld` when it does (as `$m[0]`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/H1kol))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/(?!^)\..+/', $value, $m)) {
        $result[$value] = ['tld' => $value, 'gTLD' => []];
    } else {
        $result[$m[0]]['gTLD'][] = $value;
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

If the `gTLD`s are not guaranteed to occur after the initialization of `tld`s, then more conditional checks will be required.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pcnH3))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/(?!^)\..+/', $value, $m)) {
        if (!isset($result[$value])) {
            $result[$value] = ['tld' => $value, 'gTLD' => []];
        }
    } else {
        if (!isset($result[$m[0]])) {
            $result[$m[0]] = ['tld' => $m[0], 'gTLD' => [$value]];
        } else {
            $result[$m[0]]['gTLD'][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```